# Render Django view class to either string or response

Tags: python, django

I have a template that I want to be able to both serve directly and embed in arbitrary other templates in my Django application. I tried to create a view class for it that looks like this:

```
class TemplateView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = self._create_context(request)
        return render_to_response('template.html', context)

    def get_string(self, request):
        context = self._create_context(request)
        return render_to_string('template.html', context)

    def _create_context(self, request):
        context = {}
        # Complex context initialization logic...
        return context
```

I've wired `get` to my Django URLs. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to instantiate `TemplateView` so that I can call `get_string` from other views.

There must be a better way to go about doing this. Ideas?

**Update:** I've seen some folks talking about making a request internally and using `response.content`, which would save me from having to write the `get_string` method. So, perhaps a better question is: How do I make a request to `TemplateView` from another view?

Comment: How did you wire `get` to your Django URLS? `get` is normally called via View's dispatch() method.

Comment: @DerekKwok I just meant that I'd wired `TemplateView.as_view`, which in turn invokes `get` on a `GET` request.

Answer (score 4):

I'd follow in django's CBV pattern: it determines via `dispatch` what method to return. By default based on `request.method`. Why not based on any other argument passed to `dispatch()`?

So subclass dispatch and give it a way to determine whether or not to return `get_string`.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'as_string' in kwargs:
         return self.get_string(request)        
    return super(TemplateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

response = TemplateView.as_view()(request, as_string=True)
```

Comment: Amazing idea, thank you! Is this ```return self.as_string(request)``` correct, however? Seems like it should read ```return self.get_string(request)```.