# Django: Using render_to_string() on a class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a complex subclass of DetailView to render my template.

```
class Test(DetailView):

    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    model = MyModel

    def ..my_methods.. (self, ...):
        ...
        return result

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        return context
```

How could I use this view in order to have the option of rendering the result into a string and save it in a variable?

I can think of `render_to_string()` but I am not sure how could I use it with a class based view.

**EDIT**

It is also [a good approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13737176/2996101) to calibrate the `dispatch()` method in order to `render_to_string()` only when a given keyword is applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render_to_string` expects these parameters `template_name`, `dictionary`, `context_instance` where dictionary and context_instance have default values of None. According to its definition

> Loads the given template_name and renders it with the given dictionary
>   as context. The template_name may be a string to load a single
>   template using get_template, or it may be a tuple to use
>   select_template to find one of the templates in the list. Returns a
>   string.

just import the function:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
```

and in the `get` function of your class inherited from `DetailView` just use it in the given definition format.

```
class Test(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render_to_string(<template_name>, <dictionary>)
```

The dictionary is passed as context data to the template.

Comment: just a little misspell in package name `from django.template.loader import render_to_string`