# Django CBV: Programmatically save HTML page to PDF file on the server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

Visiting the relevant url, an html page is rendered. I need to programmatically save this html page to a pdf file on the server.

**views.py**

```
class PdfView(DetailView):
    model = TheModel
    template_name = 'pdf.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
        PdfDataView.as_view(),
        name='pdf-data',
    ),
]
```

Comment: _Always_ include the version-agnostic `python` tag.

Comment: @raratiru does my answer works for you?

Comment: @andilabs I saw it a few minutes ago and upvoted, thank you! I get the idea. I am currently trying to make ends meet with the "save to server" bit of the equation and something like [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13737176/2996101) seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @raratiru if it helped you, please click accept ✅

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution saves a pdf version of the web page during the HTTP request, before the HTTP response is served to the browser.

I used [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) because it managed to take care of the unicode characters out of the box.

**views.py**

```
from weasyprint import HTML

class PdfView(DetailView):
    model = TheModel
    template_name = 'pdf.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template_response = super().get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        HTML(string=template_response.rendered_content).write_pdf(
            '/path/to/test.pdf',
            stylesheets=['/path/to/pdf.css']
        )
        return template_response
```

A better solution, outside the view, would be to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to fetch the HTML page and then create the pdf file. It is better because the server will not have to wait for the pdf to be created, potentially blocking other requests waiting to be serverd:

```
>>>import requests
>>>resp = requests.get('http://my-url/object_id')
>>>HTML(string=resp.content).write_pdf('/path/to/test.pdf', stylesheets=['/path/to/pdf.css'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an approach like below. Although it presents serving file to the end user via response, but modifying it to write file on server should be easy for you:

The functional view:

```
def pdf_sticker(request, pk):
    spot = get_object_or_404(Spot, pk=pk)
    if spot.is_certificated:
        pdf, result = render_to_pdf(
            'www/pdf_sticker.html',
            {
                'pass_smth': 'needed_in_render',
                'MEDIA_ROOT': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                'STATIC_ROOT': settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0],
                'pagesize': 'A6',
            }
        )
        if not pdf.err:
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

The helper method:

```
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

from django.template.loader import get_template


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(
        StringIO(html),
        dest=result,
        encoding='UTF-8'
    )

    return pdf, result
```

the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>


        <title>Sticker for certificated spot</title>
        <style type="text/css">
                 @font-face {
                    font-family: "Lobster";
                    src: url("{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/font/Lobster-32.ttf");
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
                }
                @font-face {
                    font-family: "Lato";
                    src: url("{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/font/Lato-Hairline.ttf");
                    font-weight: 100;
                    font-style: thin;
                }
                @font-face {
                    font-family: "Nobile";
                    src: url("{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/font/Nobile-34.ttf");
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
                }

                @page {
                    size: {{ pagesize }};
                    margin: 0.5cm;
                }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <img src="{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/{{ SPOT_PROJECT_NAME }}/certificate.png" height="260px">
            <p style="font-family:Lobster;">
                <span style="font-size:60px;">
                    {% settings_value "SPOT_PROJECT_SUBJECT" %}<br>
                </span>
                <span style=" font-size:32px;">
                    friendly spot!
                </span>
                <br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2>
                             <img src="http://{{BASE_HOST}}{% url 'www:qrencode_link' pk=spot.pk size=4 %}">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2 height=5></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2>
                            <span style="font-family:Nobile; font-size:15px;">
                            Powered by: <img src="{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/{{ SPOT_PROJECT_NAME }}/logo.png" height="50px"> </span>
                            <span style="font-family:Lobster; font-size:25px;">
                                    {{ SPOT_PROJECT_NAME }}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </p>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Working for Python 3.6, Django 2.0.

Libraries versions:

```
Django==2.0.2
xhtml2pdf==0.2b1
```

### Regarding the part of writing it to local file on server this might help:

http://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-with-python-standalone

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will not use `html2pdf` since `weasyprint` seems to be easily handling unicode characters out of the box. It also [uses one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49241376/2996101) to create the pdf file and it seems to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This function worked for me.

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
        template = get_template(template_src)
        html = template.render(context_dict)
        result = BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
        if not pdf.err:
            f = open('test2.pdf', 'wb')
            myfile = File(f)
            myfile.write(result.getvalue())
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return None
```